# Update css styles using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I want to change the color of all elements with

tags to red.

I'm doing:-

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li").style.color = "red"
```

This isn't working. But it's working with querySelectorAll method and getElementsByClassName method.

Does it mean that I can't use this technique with getElementsByTagName or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Duplicate [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the **[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements, you need to iterate over the collection to apply your style.

Please run the snippet below to see this in action:

```js
//declare function to change color of list items
function changeColor() {
  //get li tags by tag name
  let li_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
  //iterate over tags and apply the color red
  for (let i = 0; i < li_tags.length; i++) {
    li_tags[i].style.color = "red"
  }
}

//declare button as variable using the btn id
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")

//when button is clicked run the changeColor function
btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ul>
<br />
<button id="btn">Change Color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `getElementsByTagName()` method is a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not a DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

You can iterate over the HTMLCollection in different ways. For example:

```
const els = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(const el of els) {
    el.style.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    let listItems = [...document.getElementsByTagName("li")];
    listItems.forEach(li => li.style.color = "red");
```